# Authenticated YouTube Data v3 query fails with 403 Forbidden message

Tags: youtube-api

This is a c# .NET application. The app makes an OAuth2 authenticated YouTube Data v3 ChannelList query that had been working for two months. Recently, the query fails with a 403 Forbidden message from Google. It fails from our Azure Web server and when running in Visual Studio on a developer desktop. The query works for at least one user but fails for all others tested. The query (listed here) works for all users from within the API Explorer. I cannot find additional error description returned from Google.

Update (7/15/2013): The query now runs after adding the access_token to the query. Previously, it executed successfully with the access_token only in the Service object, not explicitly part of the query. Although the query is successful with access_token directly appended, we are getting a downstream JavaScript error on on the YouTube embedded player. Not sure if that is related. I see there was a .NET API update in late June. @Ikailan, did something change at Google to break the access_token auth in the Service object. Note: we DID update to the new API. **Are changes required to our code to use the June 2013 API updates?**

**Error Message** "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Method that was failing but now works with the Auth token added to the query.

```
//Gets the channel information of the current user
public static ChannelListResponse GetCurrentUserChannel(string token)
{
    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(GlobalSettings.applicationName, GlobalSettings.developerKey);
    GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = new GAuthSubRequestFactory("YouTube", GlobalSettings.applicationName);
    authFactory.Token = token;
    service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

    ChannelListResponse response = new ChannelListResponse();

    try
    {
        System.IO.Stream resultStream = service.Query(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2CtopicDetails&mine=true&access_token=" + authFactory.Token));
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(resultStream))
        {
            string value = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response = JObject.Parse(value).ToObject<ChannelListResponse>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return response;
}
```

Line that throws the exception. Added the Auth Key (see code above). Now the query executes successfully.

```
System.IO.Stream resultStream = service.Query(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet&mine=true"));
```

However, we are getting an Access Denied error for an embedded YouTube video player.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 4 in http://localhost:49185/YotaCast_Prototype/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4242, column 4 in http://localhost:49185/YotaCast_Prototype/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 360, column 9 in http://localhost:49185/YotaCast_Prototype/Scripts/foundation/foundation.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Zepto' is undefined
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 97 in http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflXN6WzI.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

Comment: We'll need a few more details to start helping. Is every user going through the 3-legged OAuth flow? Are you using long-lived tokens, or did you guys get a short lived access token and have it expire? If you can get your access token printed out, pass it to this URL as a parameter: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

Comment: Every user goes through the OAuth flow (not sure what 3-legged OAuth flow?) each time they access the Web App. Each user is presented by Google with the specific scopes to allow. This is a short-lived access token. We only access the API for a given user while that user is logged in to our application (current session). I uploaded an Access Token.

Comment: "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://gdata.youtube.com",
 "expires_in": 2178,

Comment: @IkaiLan Can you help today? Do you need more from me.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like you are using the right scopes. You are using an analytics scope and a user info scope. The read/write scope for Channel list is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube. The read only scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly. If you can post your code in the original comment I'll write a longer answer below.

Comment: @IkaiLan Do you have an update for this?

Comment: @IkaiLan Results from token info from using the updated scope list.  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
 "expires_in": 3564,
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "online"

Comment: I added the auth key to the query and now the query is working. The application is now throwing a JavaScript exception. Likely, related to this issue. I may not be retreiving the data exactly has I had previously. It looks like there were some API changes.

Comment: @IkaiLan This is the JavaScript error: Exception was thrown at line 1, column 97 in http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflXN6WzI.js

0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

Comment: That seems like a different question. You should probably close this one and open a new StackOverflow Q, because otherwise this is going to be confusing to other readers.

Comment: Solved. It looks like Google changed their auth requirements for the ChannelList query. I added the current user access_token to that query and all is well. The access_token is a property in the YouTubeService class but the token was also required on the query string. The scopes change may have also been part of the issue.

Comment: Channel List always required an access token if you were doing it for a user.

Comment: The access token is and was included as a property of the YouTubeService class and our instantiated service object. We used that object to invoke the query. Could the YouTubeService access token have been passed by the object separate from the query string? However, now the token is required in the query itself. I am trying to understand the full functionality of the YouTubeService class. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't AuthSub being deprecated? I am in the middle of upgrading my code and want to know if the above code is still good.